# Removing line between polygons in SVG

Tags: svg

How to remove the line between two adjacent polygons in SVG:

```html
    <svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <polygon points="100 100,  100 200,  200 100" style="fill: blue; fill-opacity: 1; stroke: black;stroke-width: 0;" />
    <polygon points="200 200,  100 200,  200 100" style="fill: blue; fill-opacity: 1; stroke: black;stroke-width: 0;" />
    </svg>
```

In this case it could be solved by merging the two polygons - but this is not the case if the polygons has different colors.

Comment: I see no line. Anyway it's likely antialiasing if you see it so shape-rendering="crispEdges" would be one way to fix it.

Comment: That did the trick :) https://jsfiddle.net/mortennobel/Ljrvbcxe/ (In using Safari for showing the SVG files - I did expect the behaviour to be different between different viewers).

Comment: Please write you comment as an answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG: Prevent transparent gaps between adjacent polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47451435/svg-prevent-transparent-gaps-between-adjacent-polygons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's antialiasing so shape-rendering="crispEdges" would be one way to fix it.

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
    <polygon points="100 100,  100 200,  200 100" style="fill: blue; fill-opacity: 1; stroke: black;stroke-width: 0;" />
    <polygon points="200 200,  100 200,  200 100" style="fill: blue; fill-opacity: 1; stroke: black;stroke-width: 0;" />
</svg>
```